# Docker Swarm: traffic in assigned state

Tags: docker-swarm

When I scale a service up from 1 node (Node A) to 2 nodes (Node A and Node B), I see traffic immediately being routed to both nodes (including the new Node B even though it isn't ready).

As a result, an Nginx proxy will return `502`s half the time (until Node B is ready).

Any suggestions how you can delay this traffic?

Note: this isn't waiting for another container to come up as mentioned here: [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y)
This is about delaying the network connection until the container is ready.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not configure a [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck) section, docker will assume that the container is available as soon as it is started.

Note that the initial healthcheck is only done *after* the set `interval`.

So you could add something extremely basic like testing if port 80 is connectable (you need nc in your docker image):

```
healthcheck:
  test: nc -w 1 127.0.0.1 80 < /dev/null
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 3
  start_period: 5s
```